# Custom navBar doesn't work with translucent

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

In a navcontroller I put in the viewDidLoad this code:

```
NSNumber *screenWidth = @([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width);
NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"testImg_%@w@2x.jpg", screenWidth];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
[[self navigationBar] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,image.size.height)];
[[self  navigationBar] setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

then I have as root view Controller a table view. Everything works fine but if I disable the translucent option, then the table goes under the custom nav bar.
any idea?

**UPDATE**
before setting image I set also the background with a color, and this fix my initial issue:

```
     [self.navigationBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Answer (score 1):

uncheck "Extend edges under Top Bars" in the viewcontroller properties.
[image]

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work. I set both in navViewController and tableviewController